# I try to shuffle my array but it keep saying undefined. var tab1=[{name:"gabby", age:"12"},{name:"jordan", age:"14"}]

Tags: javascript, arrays

trying to shuffle an array with this form: `var tab1 = [{name: "gabby", age: "12"}, {name: "jordan",age: "14"}]

the problem is when i run it it says Undefined and i want it to write what is inside of the array ( ex.: "Aller aux vues")

```
var affichage = function(t) {
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {   
        print("expression: " + t[i].expression + ", signification: " + t[i].signification);
    }
};

var tab1 = [{
        expression: "Aller aux vues",
        signification: "aller au cinema"
    },
    {
        expression: "Au plus sacrant",
        signification: "Au plus vite"
    },
    {
        expression: "Avoir de la misère",
        signification: "Avoir de la difficulté"
    }
];

affichage(tab1);
```

i'm not sure i understand the line --> `if (t && t.length)`

```
// fonction pour mélanger le tableau
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var temp = 0;
var shuffle = function(t) {
    if (t && t.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < t.length; ++i) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length);
            if (i !== j)
                var temp = t[i].expression;
            t[i].expression = t[j].expression;
            t[j].expression = temp;
            var temp2 = t[i].signification;
            t[i].signification = t[m].signification;
            t[m].signification = temp2
        }
    }
    return t;
};

var tab1 = [{
        expression: "Aller aux vues",
        signification: "aller au cinema"
    },
    {
        expression: "Au plus sacrant",
        signification: "Au plus vite"
    },
    {
        expression: "Avoir de la misère",
        signification: "Avoir de la difficulté"
    }
];

print("tableau avant le shuffle:" + tab1);
var tab2 = shuffle(tab1);
print("tableau apres le shuffle:" + tab2);
```

var `tab2 = shuffle(tab1)` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please don't post images of code, instead include the code in your post directly. That said, you seem to be missing a bracket near `if (i == j)`. This would become clear if you format/indent your code properly

Comment: i don't know how to do it ! that's why i post an image ... sorry !!

Comment: You just copy-paste your code like into any other editor, select it, and click the `{}` toolbar button

Comment: i think it's correct now !! thank you ! :)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: yes, when i run it it says Undefined and i want it to write what is inside of the array ( ex.:  "Aller aux vues")

Comment: In your `shuffle` function, can you tell me where the `m` in `t[m].signification` came from?

Comment: Nowhere, it's a new variable that I wanted to create to be able to trade with the value of i. And temp and temp2 are temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: m is not defined
```

This is because you refer to t[m], in the code, but m is not defined.

Notice you have have declarations for i, j and temp:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var temp = 0;
```

Perhaps you need something similar for m.

```js
// fonction pour mélanger le tableau
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var temp = 0;
var shuffle = function(t) {
  if (t && t.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; ++i) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * t.length);
      if (i !== j)
        var temp = t[i].expression;
      t[i].expression = t[j].expression;
      t[j].expression = temp;
      var temp2 = t[i].signification;
      t[i].signification = t[m].signification;
      t[m].signification = temp2
    }
  }
  return t;
};

var tab1 = [{
    expression: "Aller aux vues",
    signification: "aller au cinema"
  },
  {
    expression: "Au plus sacrant",
    signification: "Au plus vite"
  },
  {
    expression: "Avoir de la misère",
    signification: "Avoir de la difficulté"
  }
];

console.log("tableau avant le shuffle:" + tab1);
var tab2 = shuffle(tab1);
console.log("tableau apres le shuffle:" + tab2);
```